# Different context types in hadoop for mapper and combiner

Tags: java, hadoop

Hello I'm trying to implement java hadoop application. I want to make mapper of <Object, Text, NaicsAreaPair, LongWritable> (so the output of mapper will be NaicsAreaPair as key and LongWritable as value). Then I need Combiner to be like <NaicsAreaPair,LongWritable, Text,AreaWagePair> so the input is correct with mapper output, but combiner output is different from mapper output.

I have in main class this configuration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "NY statistics");
 job.setJarByClass(NYStatisticsOwnWritableComparable.class);
 job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
 job.setCombinerClass(Combiner.class);
 job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
 job.setOutputKeyClass(NaicsAreaPair.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
 //job.setPartitionerClass(Rozdelovac.class);
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
 //job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
 System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Here I have to say which output key and output value will be used. Is there any possibility to set it like ok for mapper use this output key and value but for combiner use different?

Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not. The Combiner output MUST be the same as Mapper output.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a combiner for this? 
The purpose for which Combiners are there is 'Performance' by reducing the data sent over the network.
There are several limitations like the input/output type must match the mapper output (key/value)types/reducer input(key/value) types ,the function that it performs should be associative and commutative see an example here http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/14/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-4-to-use-or-not-to-use-a-combiner/

What you want as your combiner,let it be the reducer

Comment: I used it because I wanted to have in mapper naics as key and area with wage as value. Then in Combiner I wanted to sum all of the wages per area and send it as naics as key and area with sum of wages as value and then in reducer I just wanted to find maximum for the each area in each naics.. if I won't use combiner for this I will need to use reducer 2 times (one for summing and one for maximum) won't I? And at this point combiner will make the data little bit smaller (not as many area per naics) won't it?

Comment: you can use a combiner to perform the aggregation (nothing more) so output type will be same as it's input type.In reducer you can find the maximum per input key type.